# Type annotations before ellipsis

Tags: java, annotations, type-annotation

I've seen in the [JLS section 8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) that there can be annotations before an ellipsis:

```
class X {
    void method(String @Annotation ... x) {}
}
```

My question is then rather simply: what does it mean?

In particular, what is the difference with:

```
class X {
    void method(@Annotation String ... x) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write a varargs formal parameter such as

```
void method(String... x) {}
```

then the Java compiler generates a method that takes an array of strings; whenever your source code calls the method with multiple arguments, the Java compiler packages them up into an array before calling the method.  So, it is helpful to think of a declaration like `String...` as being akin to `String[]`.  Furthermore, the annotations are interpreted the same.

Either of these annotations

```
void method(String @NonEmpty ... x) {}
void method(String @NonEmpty [] x) {}
```

applies to the array:  the type means a non-empty array of strings.  The annotation documents that the array or vararg list should not be empty.  You could use an annotation processor to enforce this at compile time or run time.

Either of these annotations

```
void method(@English String ... x) {}
void method(@English String [] x) {}
```

applies to the element type.  The annotation documents that the method takes an array of English strings.

Comment: Ah yes, I had somehow thought that annotation could not apply to arrays, but of course they can.

Answer (score 3):

[From the JLS on Where Annotations May Appear](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4)

> It is possible for an annotation to appear at a syntactic location in
>   a program where it could plausibly apply to a declaration, or a type,
>   or both.

and

> Whether an annotation applies to a declaration or to the type of the
>   declared entity - and thus, whether the annotation is a declaration
>   annotation or a type annotation - depends on the applicability of the
>   annotation's type: [...]

Therefore, the annotation in

```
void method(String @Annotation ... x) {}
```

is a [`TYPE_USE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_USE) annotation.

And the annotation in

```
void method(@Annotation String ... x) {}
```

is both a `TYPE_USE` and a [`PARAMETER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#PARAMETER) annotation.

---

You can verify this.

```
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface Annot {}
public static void method(String @Annot... arg) {}
public static void method2(@Annot String... arg) {}
```

and

```
@Target(value = ElementType.PARAMETER)
@interface Annot {}
public static void method(String @Annot... arg) {} // DOES NOT COMPILE
public static void method2(@Annot String... arg) {}
```